# How to write the replace() function for a list

Tags: python, list, replace

I am in my first year of my computer science degree and I have no background in programming, so this is probably going to be an elementary question.

So, our professor banned the use of the replace() function for all assignments because apparently, it is "cheating". I am doing an assignment where I have to use the replace function, but since I cannot use it, I just created a for loop that goes through all the elements in the list. To give an example, if I want to replace all occurrences of "1" in the list with "5"s,

```
for number in list_of_numbers:
    if number == "1":
        number = "5"
```

It does its job but I am just curious if there is a more efficient way to do it without using replace()?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It doesn't "do its job". Your code has no effect at all.

Comment: what would be better is to make your own function(you could call it my_replace) and try to figure out how to write the replace function

Comment: _It does its job_ Are you sure?  Did you print list_of_numbers after running your function to see if the list really was changed?

Comment: The professor banned using the `replace()` function because if you were allowed to use it, this would be a trivial assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is probably the way your professor wanted it.

You could also make it a list comprehension. It would look something like this

```
def f(x):
    if x=="1": return "5"
    else: return x

list_of_numbers = [f(x) for x in list_of_numbers]
```

I would make sure that the solution you have does what you think it does though. Also be sure that you actually want to deal with strings of numbers, and not just the integers themselves.

Comment: A list comprehension is not equivalent, it creates a new list. Also the OP's way doesn't work, so is probably not what their professor wanted.

Comment: Also, I doubt that anyone is looking for a string. It should probably be integers instead!

Comment: to fix @jonrsharpe's fair critique, you could just do `list_of_numbers[:] = [f(x) for x in list_of_numbers]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

map(lambda x: '5' if x == '1' else x, list_of_numbers)

btw, you can try to learn some lambda and map function in python. It is useful

Comment: the pythonic way to do this is with a list comp: `['5' if x == '1' else x for x in list_of_numbers]`

Comment: Again, this *creates a new list* rather than modifying the list in place, which is **not** what `.replace` does. Also, as acushner has stated, this would be better as a list-comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a professor would want:

```
n = len(list_of_numbers)
for i in range(n):
    if list_of_numbers[i]==1: list_of_numbers[i]=5

print (list_of_numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write `my_replace` function as follows (it replaces `n1` by `n2` in list `l`):

```
def my_replace(n1, n2, l):
    for item in l:
        if item == n1:
            l[l.index(item)] = n2
```

**Outpout:**

```
>>> list_of_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 8, 7]
>>> my_replace(1, 5, list_of_numbers)
>>> list_of_numbers
[5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 5, 8, 7]
```

You may also use a list comprehension to avoid updating the original list:

```
[x if x != 1 else 5 for x in list_of_numbers]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> [x if x != 1 else 5 for x in list_of_numbers]
[5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 5, 8, 7]
```